# Как в реакт приложении изменить локльный json файл?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Делаю приложение - конвертер величин на реакте. Величины и правила конвертации храняться в json файле  локально. Нужно реализовать возможность расширения списка величин добавлением правил конвертации в этот файл. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Реализуйте через RestAPI/GraphQL. Из браузерной среды напрямую невозможно работать с файловой системой

Comment: @Yugofx Почему невозможно? Я конечно могу ошибаться, но я не вижу не одной причины почему это нельзя сделать

Comment: @Ceri, буквально изменить файл (изменить/создать/удалить) из окна веб-приложения невозможно, иначе это просто черная дырища в безопасности. Браузерное расширение - другое дело.